# how I must use digits function in matlab

Tags: matlab, double, digits

i have code and use double function several time to convert sym to double.to increase precision , I want to use digits function. 
I want to know it is enough that I write digits in the top of code or I must write digits in above of every double function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`digits` set's the precision until it is changed again. Calling `digits()` without any input you get the precision to verify it's set correct.

In many cases `digis` has absoluetly no influence on symbolic variables because an analytical solution is found. This means there are no precision errors unless you convert to double. When convertig, `digits` should be set to at least `16` because this matches double precision.